# Ошибка импорта модуля в unittest

Tags: python, python-3.x, юнит-тесты

Написал юнит-тест для сервера на Python, который при запуске генерирует ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\unittest\case.py", line 59, in testPartExecutor
    yield
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\unittest\case.py", line 615, in run
    testMethod()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 34, in testFailure
    raise self._exception
ImportError: Failed to import test module: server_test
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 154, in loadTestsFromName
    module = __import__(module_name)
  File "D:\Develop\FireChat_Messenger\server\server_test.py", line 2, in <module>
    from server import server
ImportError: cannot import name 'server' from 'server' (D:\Develop\FireChat_Messenger\server\server.py)
```

При этом модуль `server.py` находится в одной папке с модулями `__init__.py` и `server_test.py`.

`server_test.py`:

```
from datetime import datetime
from server import server
import unittest


class ServerTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_status(self):
        dn = datetime.now()
        self.assertEqual(server.status(), {
            "server_version": "v0.1",
            "is_ON": True,
            "time": dn.strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")
        })


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

`server.py`:

```
import datetime

def status():
    return {
            "server_version": "v0.1",
            "is_ON": True,
            "time": dn.strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")
           }
```

Код в модуле `__init__.py` отсутствует.

Помогите решить эту проблему.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вместо:

```py
from server import server
```

Пишите:

```py
import server
```

`server_test.py` и `server.py` лежат в одной папке, если бы `server_test.py` лежал выше, то импорт был бы правильным.